# Is this word "manuducant" a typo or an obscure word?

Tags: vocabulary, mathematics, neo-latin

I have the following sentence from Euler's *De Serie Lambertina* (I've already asked half a dozen questions about this paper), and one of the words *manuducant* (manvdvcant), shown in the snippet below, doesn't seem to be a word as written.
[image]

It seems like the sentence reads

> Operationes analiticas exponere, quae ad cognitionem verae summae seriei *Lambertinae* manuducant.

Which translates to

> Set forth the analytical operations, which [manuducant] to the understanding of the actual sum of the Lambert series.

As I see it, the word relates to *duco*, so it would be something like "which leads to the understanding...", but I'm unsure of the intention here, maybe "manu ducant"?

Comment: "Manu ducant" certainly seems to make more sense than "manducant", the other interpretation that comes to mind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Manuductio* (verb: *manuduco*) is a late Latin word that literally means, "leading by the hand." See, for instance, ["Mind Forming and *Manuductio* in Aquinas"](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/637654/pdf) (pay-wall protected), which discusses the word in the works of Thomas Aquinas.

The *Dictionnaire latin-français des auteurs du Moyen-Age* gives as its earliest citation a work by Thomas Gallus (early 13th c.)--though, as cnread helpfully points out, the related word *manuductor* does have earlier attestations. Thomas Aquinas uses *manuductio* and *manuduco* quite frequently, as you can verify in the [Index Thomisticus](https://www.corpusthomisticum.org/it/index.age).

Based on the fact that the earliest citations of this word in Latin come from commentaries on an extremely popular work translated from Greek, Pseudo-Dionysus's *De Divinis Nominibus*, it is likely that it came into Latin as a literal translation of a slightly more common Greek term: [*χειραγωγία*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dxeiragwgi%2Fa), literally "hand-leading." At this time, many of the Latin translations of Greek works (such as those of William of Moerbeke) were scrupulously literal.

*Manuductio* seems to become a common word in Scholastic and Later Latin (such as the work you cite by Euler). The intended sense is a little more specific than just "introduction": it generally refers to **"leading someone to an understanding of something through specific examples."**

Comment: OLD does list a noun manuductor, 'a guide', though it cites only a single inscription (CIL 4.3905).

Comment: also https://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#57880

Comment: (Speaking from a position of complete ignorance on the matter) I wonder why Latin swapped 'manu' as opposed to 'chiro', for 'xeira'.

Comment: @Strawberry "chiro-" would be the Greek prefix. Latin sometimes uses the Greek prefixes, but it's more standard to do a translation. As an analogy from English, we could use "circumlocution" but it's more normal to "talk in circles."